# Passport.js Render error 401 with failureRedirect

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, mongoose, passport.js

i am using passport.js local strategy for both signup and login curently without flashing errors when i try to provide correct data to any one it pass data and move to successRedirect`/home` while on any type of wrong data or unregistered data in login case or duplicated data in signup case it goes to failuerRedirect `/login` but rather rending that view its shows erorr 401 with a text `Unauthorized`

following is my code

Passport.js file

```
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use('User.signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
}, function (req, email, password, done) {
        var FirstName = req.body.Firstname;
        var LastName = req.body.Lastname;
        var email = req.body.email;
        var RollNo = req.body.rollno;
        var Gender = req.body.Gender;
        var password = req.body.password;
    User.findOne({'email': email}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, false, {signupMessage: 'Email is already in use.'});
        }
        var newUser = new User();
        newUser.First_Name = FirstName;
        newUser.Last_Name = LastName;
        newUser.email = email;
        newUser.Roll_No = RollNo;
        newUser.Gender = Gender;
        newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
        newUser.save(function(err, result) {
           if (err) {
               return done(err);
           }
           return done(null, newUser);
        });
    });
}));

passport.use('user.login' , new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
}, function (req , email  , password , done ){
    User.findOne({'email' : email} ,function(err , user) {
        if(err){
                    return done(err)
                }
        if(!user){
                    return done(null , false )
                }
        if(!user.validPassword(password)){
                    return done(null , false )
                }

        return done(null , user);
    });
}));
```

User Model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  First_Name : { type : String , required : true  , minLength: 2 },
  Last_Name : { type : String , required : true  , minLength : 2},
  email : { type : Schema.Types.Mixed, unique : true, required : true, dropDups: true },
  Roll_No : { type : Schema.Types.Mixed, unique : true, required : true, dropDups: true },
  Gender :  String ,
  password : { type : Schema.Types.Mixed, required : true}
},{collection : 'Users'});

UserSchema.methods.encryptPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(5), null);
};

UserSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
}
var User = mongoose.model('User' , UserSchema); 

module.exports = User;
```

and Routes

```
/* Get Login */

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login');
});

/* Post Login */

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('user.login', {
  successRedirect : '/home',
  failuerRedirect : '/login',
  failuerFlash : true
}));


/* Get SignUp */

router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('signup');
});

/* regester New user */

router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('User.signup' , {
  successRedirect : '/home',
  failuerRedirect : '/signup',
  failuerFlash: true
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled some words in your routes, check out the code below:

```
/* Get Login */

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login');
});

/* Post Login */

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('user.login', {
  successRedirect : '/home',
  failureRedirect : '/login',
  failureFlash : true
}));


/* Get SignUp */

router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('signup');
});

/* register New user */

router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('User.signup' , {
  successRedirect : '/home',
  failureRedirect : '/signup',
  failureFlash: true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently i worked on passport local i have past the git url, i can't find the error in your code
https://github.com/sourabhkum/expressapp